# How to generate tabs with list

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to generate `p:tabView` with Java list. This is so far the code that I have tested:

JSF page:

```
<p:tabView value="#{bean.tabs}" var="listItem">

    <p:tab title="#{listItem.tabid}">

`   <ui:include src="#{listItem.tabfilename}" />

    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Managed bean:

```
List<TabObject> tabs = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tabs.add(new TabObject("tab1.xhtml", "General"));
        tabs.add(new TabObject("tab2.xhtml", "History"));

    }

    public class TabObject {

        String tabfilename;
        String tabid;

        public TabObject(String tabfilename, String tabid) {
            super();
            this.tabfilename = tabfilename;
            this.tabid = tabid;
        }

        public String getTabfilename() {
            return tabfilename;
        }

        public void setTabfilename(String tabfilename) {
            this.tabfilename = tabfilename;
        }

        public String getTabid() {
            return tabid;
        }

        public void setTabid(String tabid) {
            this.tabid = tabid;
        }        
    }

    public List<TabObject> getTabs() {
        return tabs;
    }
```

But for some reason it's not working. I can see the tabs header generated but the body of the tabs are empty. Can you help me to fix my code?

UPDATE:

Simple tabs are working very well:

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:tab id="tab1" title="General" >
        <ui:include src="tab1.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab2" title="Group Accounts" >
        <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>   
    <p:tab id="tab3" title="History" >
        <ui:include src="tab3.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: try first to success with custom tab (no list - just place several tabs with `<ui:include`) , than after it will work - do the same with list...

Comment: post updated. I already tested it.

Comment: Ok, took @BalusC suggestion and set up a test environment. I assumed that what you were trying to do would work because I have done something similar. I think what is happening is that because of the timing of the building of the DOM tree, your list iterator is empty when it attempts to do the ui:include. Therefore it never includes your tab file. The reason it worked for me is because I wasn't trying to use a tab iterator. I was just including a block of code so I bound it directly to a variable on my backing bean, then changed it as I needed. But it isn't the same issue you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is your getters/setters. It assumes the convention of get(Capitol letter).
Change them to getTabfilename, setTabfilename, etc. on your backing bean.

Comment: Can you try the following to see confirm that you are getting the return you expect from the backing bean? Replace your tab declaration with <p:tab title="#{listItem.tabfilename}">. Since you said the tabs were appearing with the correct title, they should now show the name of the file you are trying to include. Are they showing the correct filenames? Would you also please update the code in your question to reflect the changes you have made?

Comment: So were you able to confirm that the correct tabfilenames were coming back from the backing bean?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Again it's not working. I changed the code - I can see appropriate file name when I print the content but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like your backing bean is correct. So now it sounds like the problem is either that it cannot find the file to include or there is an error in the code you are including. When you switch your code back, are there any errors in the stacktrace?

Comment: Wow, very fast response. No I don't get any errors in Glassfish's log or Firebug.

Comment: If bad getter/setters were the cause of his problem, he would have faced an `ELException` instead of a successful render with empty tabs. So, the bad getter/setters are just result of careless formulation of the question. The OP wasn't able to type valid code from top of head, neither did he care if the code in the question properly represents the real code. This answer is therefore invalid and can better be deleted as it doesn't answer the concrete problem at all. You could continue discussing in the question's comments (or in chat).

Comment: I don't see any problems. If you were to combine your simple tab example with your dynamic by hardcoding the include (yes, all pages would get the same include... for now) does it work?

Comment: I suggest to just run the very same code in your sandbox environment to see the problem yourselves :)